# How to select specific columns from read_csv which start with specific word?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a big csv file, nearly 400 columns
I want to read only columns starting with 'A' and with 'X'. For example, I have the following columns:

- A_1
- A_2
- Q_1
- Q_2
- D_1
- X_1
- X_2

When I read from the csv file with using pandas, I want to select only:

- A_1
- A_2
- X_1
- X_2

And I don't know how many As and Xs I have.

Comment: See the description of `usecols` in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read the file twice: once for the headers only and once for the actual data:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', usecols=lambda col: col.startswith('A_') or col.startswith('X_'))
```

Comment: @BigBen, thanks. I have let my pandas knowledge slip a little lately.